# what type does session.queryover return

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm looking at some code that I have for nhibernate where I'm applying where clauses based on a few conditions. I have something like this:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<Client>().Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false);
if (status == "active")
   query.Where(x => x.IsActive == true);
```

here there are no issues, I'm able to say: `query.where(xxx)`

however when I change this to:

```
IQueryOver query = session.QueryOver<Client>().Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false);
if (status == "active")
    //squiggly red lines on the line below!!!
    query.Where(x => x.IsActive == true);
```

my `query.where(xxxx)` under the `if` gets red squiggly lines. I checked the return type for `session.QueryOver` and it returns an `IQueryOver` type, why is it complaining?

Is it because I'm trying to make the query object of the interface type when it should be of a concrete class that implements the interface?

Comment: You dont need to implement that interface.

Comment: Can return any value or instance like singletons, dtos, entities. Depends the queries, projections, transformers, etc.

Comment: If you get a red squiggly line, there should also be a compile error that might give you some indication of what is wrong. If there is no compile error, then probably the problem is that the editor is acting up - sometimes it gets stuck showing errors that aren't there.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you deal with dynamic queries using `QueryOver`:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<Client>()
    .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false);

if (status == "active")
   query = query.Where(x => x.IsActive == true);

var clients = query.List(); // To execute the query and get the result (root entity)
```